# Can't print the json if response code is 400 in afnetworking?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking make post request to server.If my response code is 400 then i am not able to print the json response.

**This is my code**

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"123", @"post_id",
                            arr_friendsTags, @"tagged_user", nil];
    AFJSONRequestSerializer *requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    [requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [requestSerializer setValue:api_key forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    manager.requestSerializer = requestSerializer;
    AFJSONResponseSerializer *responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript", @"text/html", nil];
    manager.responseSerializer = responseSerializer;
    [manager POST:url parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)

     {
         NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
         [self activityIndicator:@"hide"];
         NSDictionary* json =responseObject;


     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         [self activityIndicator:@"hide"];
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     }];'
```

Comment: Please suggest me how can i get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Response code 400 depicts failure. And hence the control passes to failure block, and not success block.

> **Status Code 400**
>
> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.

See [this link](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) for a list of HTTP codes.

Comment: but when i make request from chrome rest client then i am displaying json response message.

Comment: 400 is a client side failure status code, hence something is wring with your url. Can you show your url?

Comment: No it's not.  It's part of the HTTP response and hence an HTTP server was involved somewhere.  It's not an URL issue, but a problem with the HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

I'd think that status 400 will use the "failure" block, not the "success" block. Have a look at error. But it is quite likely that no JSON is returned by the server for errors.